# django, postgres 8.4, psycopg 2.2.2, python 2.7, mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, postgresql, mod-wsgi, psycopg

I've installed django/postgres on local django server and works fine.  I'm trying to get Apache working.  I've set up the mod_wsgi and was able to get a "Hello World", and restart Apache.  I'm almost there, but when I bring up localhost/index.html I get this server error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImproperlyConfigured while rendering: 
'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2' isn't an available database 
backend. 
[Thu Sep 02 13:46:30 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Try using 
django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of: 
[Thu Sep 02 13:46:30 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     'dummy', 
'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3' 
[Thu Sep 02 13:46:30 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Error was: 
cannot import name utils
```

Is it possible that mod_wsgi and the version psycopg are incompatible?  Has anyone tried this type of setup?

**Update 1:**

I downgraded to 2.6, mod_wsgi, psycopg2 and still get this error in apache log file.

> Fri Sep 03 12:17:41 2010] [error]
>   [client 97.80.165.181]   File
>   "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py",
>   line 77, in  [Fri Sep 03
>   12:17:41 2010] [error] [client
>   97.80.165.181]     connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS] [Fri Sep
>   03 12:17:41 2010] [error] [client
>   97.80.165.181]   File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py",
>   line 91, in **getitem** [Fri Sep 03
>   12:17:41 2010] [error] [client
>   97.80.165.181]     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE']) [Fri Sep 03
>   12:17:41 2010] [error] [client
>   97.80.165.181]   File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py",
>   line 49, in load_backend [Fri Sep 03
>   12:17:41 2010] [error] [client
>   97.80.165.181]     raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg) [Fri
>   Sep 03 12:17:41 2010] [error] [client
>   97.80.165.181] TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImproperlyConfigured while
>   rendering:
>   'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'
>   isn't an available database backend. 
>   [Fri Sep 03 12:17:41 2010] [error]
>   [client 97.80.165.181] Try using
>   django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is
>   one of: [Fri Sep 03 12:17:41 2010]
>   [error] [client 97.80.165.181]
>   'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle',
>   'postgresql', 'postgresql_psycopg2',
>   'sqlite3' [Fri Sep 03 12:17:41 2010]
>   [error] [client 97.80.165.181] Error
>   was: cannot import name utils

Do you know what it might indicate?

**Update 2:**

The cause is in the file django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py, version 2.2.2, line number 9:
from django.db import utils

But I still don't know how to fix this.
There is a file django/db/utils.py, so it should work. And it works for the development server, after all. But not for Apache + mod_wsgi

Comment: From memory this is actually to do with a certain Window C runtime DLL not being linked into Apache as it is with Python. There is something in psycopg2 C extension module which is dependent upon it and because it is missing it fails. The error though being seen is the obscure one above which doesn't really give a pointer to the problem. I believe the pyscopg2 people are aware of the issue. Not sure what they are going to do about it, but there was some recent activity about it on their issue tracker. But then my memory could be wrong and that is all fantasy.

Comment: If anybody using Django 1.4.x winds up on this question ... Try upgrading to the most recent version of Django (1.4.2 at the time of writing). I was getting an error similar to this in 2012 using Django 1.4.1. I updated to Django 1.4.2 and stopped getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this Ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14013) helps you:

> or whatever it is worth, I have
>   confirmed that if I downgrade python
>   to 2.6 and then likewise downgrade
>   mod_wsgi and psycopg2, Django will
>   work with Postgres on Apache as
>   expected